# Bash Script - Traffic Shaping

Tags: bash, bandwidth, tc

hey all, I was wondering if you could have a look at my script and help me add a few things to it,

1. How do I get it to find how many active ethernet ports I have? and how do I filter more than 1 ethernet port
2. How I get this to do a range of IP address?
3. Once I have a few ethenet ports I need to add traffic control to each one

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# Name of the traffic control command.
TC=/sbin/tc

# The network interface we're planning on limiting bandwidth.

IF=eth0 # Network card interface

# Download limit (in mega bits)
DNLD=10mbit # DOWNLOAD Limit

# Upload limit (in mega bits)
UPLD=1mbit # UPLOAD Limit

# IP address range of the machine we are controlling
IP=192.168.0.1 # Host IP

# Filter options for limiting the intended interface.
U32="$TC filter add dev $IF protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 u32"

start() {

    # Hierarchical Token Bucket (HTB) to shape bandwidth

    $TC qdisc add dev $IF root handle 1: htb default 30 #Creates the root schedlar
    $TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate $DNLD #Creates a child schedlar to shape download
    $TC class add dev $IF parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate $UPLD #Creates a child schedlar to shape upload
    $U32 match ip dst $IP/24 flowid 1:1 #Filter to match the interface, limit download speed
    $U32 match ip src $IP/24 flowid 1:2 #Filter to match the interface, limit upload speed
}


stop() {

    # Stop the bandwidth shaping.
    $TC qdisc del dev $IF root

}

restart() {

    # Self-explanatory.
    stop
    sleep 1
    start

}

show() {

    # Display status of traffic control status.
    $TC -s qdisc ls dev $IF

}

case "$1" in

    start)

        echo -n "Starting bandwidth shaping: "
        start
        echo "done"
        ;;

    stop)

        echo -n "Stopping bandwidth shaping: "
        stop
        echo "done"
        ;;

    restart)

        echo -n "Restarting bandwidth shaping: "
        restart
        echo "done"
        ;;

    show)

        echo "Bandwidth shaping status for $IF:"
        show
        echo ""
        ;;

    *)

        pwd=$(pwd)
        echo "Usage: tc.bash {start|stop|restart|show}"
        ;;

esac

exit 0
```

thanks

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: what did you do to get the code to format correctly?

Comment: @Iain: The markdown on this site doesn't like code that immediately follows a numbered list so I inserted a `---` hrule between them. Anything would have worked though.

Comment: i just copied and paste it from notepad

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Cheers - I've not encountered that before.

Comment: This looks suspiciously like homework, to me... Could you reword/expand your question?  I don't understand what you mean by 'filter' in part "1" and I don't understand what you mean by 'do' in part "2", and I don't understand what you mean by 'control' in part "3".

Comment: its do with my degree, i have tried to explain below in your answer

Answer (score 1):

If they have not been renamed, you can find all ethernet devices by looking for directories matching `eth*` in `/sys/class/net/`. For applying these operations to multiple NICs and IP addresses, look into [for loops](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loops.html). Here is an example

```
#!/bin/bash  

ADDRESSES="192.0.2.1 192.0.2.2"  

for I in /sys/class/net/eth*  
do  
    I=$(basename $I)  
    for A in $ADDRESSES  
    do  
        echo $I $A  
    done  
done
```

On a system with two ethernet devices, this would output

> eth0 192.0.2.1
>   eth0 192.0.2.2
>   eth1 192.0.2.1
>   eth1 192.0.2.2

Comment: i would apply it like this?,

Addresses="192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254" or can i use 192.168.1.0

for INT in /sys/class/net/eth*
do
    INT=$(basename $INT)
    for A in $adresses
do
echo $int %A
done
done

Comment: You need to spend more time learning bash shell scripting and the tc command syntax. I'm not convinced that you've made a good faith effort to do this yet, and it's not helpful for you to receive code you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Get a list of ethernet links:

`/sbin/ip link`

Get a list of connected ethernet links:

`/sbin/ip link | grep 'UP'`

I cannot understand the rest of your question.

Comment: Hi Jeff, i need the script to work with different interfaces, and ip ranges, this is aimed at a corparate network so e.g 192.168.1.0 network or ethernet port 1 is the external port and the internal port is ethernet 2.

is that easy to incorporate in my code?

Comment: With /bin/sh and /bin/bash you can access parameters given to the script via the $1 $2 $3 ... $n variables so you could write a bash script that takes your addresses as arguments. If you want to get fancy, checkout the bash getopts built-in